# Intersection between set P module

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

> Let p be an odd prime and let Zp denote (the field of) integers modulo
> p. How many elements are in the set {x² : x ∈ Zp } ∩ {y² + 1 : y ∈ Zp
> }?

Now i am REALLY confused about that

Isnt the first set {0,1,4,9,16,...,(p-1)²}
and the second set {1,5,10,17,...,(p-1)²+1}
?

The intersection is such that (1) need to have solution:

$x² = y² + 1$ (1)

The next square after x is (x+1)², and the square before it is (x-1)².

But (1) says that the square before x² is x²-1, so we have:

$(x-1)² = x²-1 =>  x = 1$, so the only solution possible is (x,y) = (1,0).
In fact, we have 1 in both sets, and it ends the solutions!

But the answer is (p + 3)/4 if p ≡ 1 (mod 4), and (p + 1)/4 if p ≡ 3 (mod 4).

What is that?

Comment: Write down very explicitly what each set is when $p = 5$.

Comment: (1) does not imply that $(x-1)^2=x^2-1$, I don't understand how you deduced that? In fact for say $p=7$ our equation (1) has two solutions: $(x,y)=(3,1)$ and $(x,y)=(4,1)$.

Comment: Together with the trivial $(1,0)$ solution this gives us $\{1,2\}$ as the intersection you look for. Which indeed has $2$ elements corresponding to $(7+1)/4$.